# generating an OAuth signature base with python

Tags: python, oauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementaion HMAC-SHA1 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338661/implementaion-hmac-sha1-in-python)

`I am attempting to do some OAuth authentication with python, but my oauth_signature keeps getting rejected.  Python 3 is pretty new to me, so can someone tell me what is wrong with this code:

```
api_key = 'string'
api_secret = 'another_string'
sig_key = api_secret + '&' + api_key
hmac_alg = hmac.new(sig_key.encode('utf-8'), sig_base_str.encode('utf-8'),hashlib.sha1)

signature_base = base64.b64encode(hmac_alg.digest())
url = url_base + '?' + 'oauth_signature=' + urllib.parse.quote(str(signature_base.decode('utf-8')),'') + '&' + str(param_str)
```

param_str is a `&` delimited string of my input parameters.  The HTTP service seems to be reading that fine as it will change the output response based on what i asked for.  It just keeps rejecting my signature.  I think hmac is the culprit.

Comment: I think my question lies in converting the pseudocode to python.  since hmac doesn't accept strings.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
api_key = b'string'
api_secret = b'another_string'
```

From python documentation

> PEP 3112: Byte Literals. The b"..." string literal notation (and its
>   variants like b'...', b"""...""", and br"...") now produces a literal
>   of type bytes.

Comment: Seems like you have answered a completely different question than the one that was asked.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying.  I tried using this `key = b'secret&key'` and still no dice