# Generating signature for API access (Oauth 1.0)

Tags: python, signature

I am trying to access an API using python and oauth 1.0. I cant get how to generate a oauth_signature. Below is my code so far, hope someone can help.

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib.parse
import time
from random import getrandbits


api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_secret_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

consumer = oauth.Consumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
token = oauth.Token(access_key, access_secret_key)

client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

nonce = str(getrandbits(64))
print(nonce)

url = 'https://secure.tmsandbox.co.nz/Oauth/Authorize?oauth_token='

params = {'oauth_version': "1.0", 
          'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(), 
          'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
          'oauth_consumer_key': CONSUMER_KEY,
          'oauth_token': access_key,
          'oauth_nonce' : nonce, 
          'oauth_consumer_key': consumer.key,
          'oauth_signature': 'el078a5AXGi43FBDyfg5yWY',
          }

req = oauth.Request(method="POST", url='https://secure.tmsandbox.co.nz/Oauth/RequestToken?', parameters=params)



# Sign the request.
signature_method = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, token)
```

***How api developers suggest I access it:***

> The oauth_signature is a little harder to come up with and is where
>   most people trip up. To generate a signature you start with a base
>   string that begins with the HTTP method and the URL encoded address
>   you are calling (without the query string). As we are getting a
>   request token, this will be a POST request to
>   https://secure.trademe.co.nz/Oauth/RequestToken?scope=MyTradeMeRead,MyTradeMeWrite
>   (note that in this example the scope parameter is used to request
>   read/write access). This is the start of our base string:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.trademe.co.nz%2FOauth%2FRequestToken
```

> Notice that we separated these with an ampersand (&). Sort all the
>   parameter keys (oauth_nonce, etc) and any query string parameters
>   alphabetically (excluding the oauth_signature as that is what we are
>   generating) and append them in a separate string, [name]=[value]
>   separating each with an ampersand. URL encode this and append it to
>   the end of the base string, preceded by an ampersand.

Comment: Why import oauth 2?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8339781/3205900) .It explains how to use HMAC - SHA1 signature method and access a website using OAuth.

Comment: found an interesting method in that thread, might look into this instead of encrypting : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32060758/5932561)