# Verification of signature failed Oauth 1 Upwork API

Tags: oauth, odesk

Hi I followed [the upwork developers site](https://developers.upwork.com) and [the twitter oauth signature generation document](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures) and I did the following:

```
timestamp = int(time.time())
nonce = ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(30)])
url = 'https://www.upwork.com/api/auth/v1/info.json'
quoted_url = quote('https://www.upwork.com/api/auth/v1/info.json')
to_hash = 'GET' + '&' + url + '&'
param_string = 'oauth_consumer_key=' + UPWORK_KEY + '&oauth_nonce=' + nonce + '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=' + str(timestamp) + '&oauth_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN + '&oauth_verifier=' + UPWORK_VERIFIER
to_hash += quote(param_string)
hashed = hmac.new(UPWORK_SECRET + '&' + ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, to_hash, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
r = requests.get('https://www.upwork.com/api/auth/v1/info.json?oauth_consumer_key=' + UPWORK_KEY + '&oauth_signature=' + hashed  + '&oauth_nonce=' + nonce + '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=' + str(timestamp) + '&oauth_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN + '&oauth_verifier=' + UPWORK_VERIFIER)
r.text
```

But when I do this, I get:

```
u'{"server_time":1472207775,"error":{"status":401,"code":401,"message":"Verification of signature failed."}}'
```

However the following works fine:

```
client = upwork.Client(UPWORK_KEY, UPWORK_SECRET, oauth_access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, oauth_access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
client.auth.get_info()
{u'info': {u'portrait_32_img': u'https://odesk-prod-portraits.s3.amazonaws.com/Users:dasugovinda:PortraitUrl_32?AWSAccessKeyId=1XVAX3FNQZAFC9GJCFR2&Expires=2147483647&Signature=77Ab%2BTxcps9PIYCfPIZZuDpXAiY%3D&1470127549683826', u'capacity': {u'buyer': u'yes', u'affiliate_manager': u'no', u'provider': u'yes'}, u'company_url': u'', u'has_agency': u'0', u'portrait_50_img': u'https://odesk-prod-portraits.s3.amazonaws.com/Users:dasugovinda:PortraitUrl_50?AWSAccessKeyId=1XVAX3FNQZAFC9GJCFR2&Expires=2147483647&Signature=K6Ea0Z6QSmBGcg%2BRCQUAvrai%2FKw%3D&1470127549683826', u'portrait_100_img': u'https://odesk-prod-portraits.s3.amazonaws.com/Users:dasugovinda:PortraitUrl_100?AWSAccessKeyId=1XVAX3FNQZAFC9GJCFR2&Expires=2147483647&Signature=Dht5wFsI%2FDpDDeURkY6KefP4yvc%3D&1470127549683826', u'location': {u'city': u'Santa Clara', u'state': u'CA', u'country': u'United States'}, u'ref': u'5356164', u'profile_url': u'https://www.upwork.com/users/~01d7463c22a4e5c195'}, u'auth_user': {u'timezone': u'America/Tijuana', u'first_name': u'Govinda', u'last_name': u'Dasu', u'timezone_offset': u'-25200'}, u'server_time': u'1472209119'}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer by @Blairg23 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338661/implementaion-hmac-sha1-in-python), I figured out the following solution:

```
url = 'https://www.upwork.com/api/auth/v1/info.json'
auth = OAuth1(UPWORK_KEY, UPWORK_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
r = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
r.text
```

Just using an already-implemented version of oauth saves you a huge headache.

Comment: So, Could it works without  ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET? In my case, I just have consumer_key and consumer_secret, how can I implement  OAuth version 1.0a with HMAC-SHA1?