# Verifying incoming requests on Python3 by HMAC-SHA1

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, hmac

I need to validate incoming request using HMAC-SHA1. The main issue for me is to create the base string for it. Are  there any libraries for python that can generate the [base string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8339781/4592608) from the request and the if its possible, made validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you are not asking about OAuth 1.0 requests, you are asking about the sign and verify function, right?

If you this is what you are asking, I'm not sure if there are any libraries, but in [Authlib](https://authlib.org/)'s code, there is a module to do sign and verify signatures: https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/oauth1/rfc5849/signature.py

Checkout:

1. sign_hmac_sha1 https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/oauth1/rfc5849/signature.py#L350

```
def sign_hmac_sha1(client, request):
    """Sign a HMAC-SHA1 signature."""
    base_string = generate_signature_base_string(request)
    return hmac_sha1_signature(
        base_string, client.client_secret, client.token_secret)
```

2. verify_hmac_sha1 https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/oauth1/rfc5849/signature.py#L368

```
def verify_hmac_sha1(request):
    """Verify a HMAC-SHA1 signature."""
    base_string = generate_signature_base_string(request)
    sig = hmac_sha1_signature(
        base_string, request.client_secret, request.token_secret)
    return hmac.compare_digest(sig, request.signature)
```

You can learn from Authlib code. But if you are just want to send OAuth 1.0 requests, you can use Authlib directly. Documentation is here: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/oauth1.html

Comment: Thank you very much @lepture! Seems, it is what i looking for. Do you know how to install server to the Django, because i have an error when it try to use signature.py. `'Request' object has no attribute 'uri` , Thank you once again!

Comment: that request is created by Authlib, you can find it in https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/oauth1/rfc5849/wrapper.py#L17

Comment: Can you please show example in your answer how to install this library and call this functions. Or i can create new topic if its needed

Comment: i've created new topic, will be appraciated if you'll help me with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043331/how-to-implement-hmac-sha1-verification-in-django-using-authlib