# HMAC-SHA1 in Python3 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, hmac

As was described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8339781/4592608) answer i've implement HMAC-SHA1 signature method.

```
def sign_request():
    from hashlib import sha1
    import hmac

    key = b"CONSUMER_SECRET&"  
    basestr = b"BASE_STRING"
    hashed = hmac.new(key, basestr, sha1)
    return hashed.digest().encode("base64").rstrip('\n')
```

But i've got `AttributeError`, `'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`. As i understood, that is why i'm using Python3, but i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because it is a byte and you are trying to encode like string. I fixed it:

```
from base64 import encodebytes
def sign_request():
    from hashlib import sha1
    import hmac

    key = b"CONSUMER_SECRET&"  
    basestr = b"BASE_STRING"
    hashed = hmac.new(key, basestr, sha1)
    return str(encodebytes(hashed.digest())).rstrip('\n')
print(sign_request())
```